# How to implement SwingWorker in multithreaded Swing MVC client-server program?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets, model-view-controller

I've created a battleShip online game that works on a client - server - client architecture. It uses TCP sockets to comunicate.

Server program is a very easy program, that creates it's own serverThread when a new client is connected.

The problem is in the client.

Client follows MVC architecture, where **Model** is represented by an Object shared between View and Controller.

**View** is where all GUI istances (with input listeners etc..) take place.

**Controller** is where takes place the server-client comunication over TCP sockets.
NOTE: Server can send Packets to let Controller update GUI, and Controllers has 
several children-threads that make time-consuming tasks and then update GUI

**Both View and Controller run on different Thread.**
**Every GUI updating tasks run on EDT thanks to swingutilities.invokelater**

The problem is that usually entire game works fine, but sometimes, with no possibilities to reproduce the error, the GUI freezes.
I've read a lot of posts online about this question and I think the problem is that View, Controller and other threads, can update the GUI with no synchronization at all.

Anyway, what would be the best way to implement a SwingWorker in a program like this? Wherever there is the need to deal with GUI should i use a SwingWorker?
and will it solve my GUI-freezing problem?

I am a bit confused on how SwingWorker should be implemented...

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english.

EDIT:
After some experimentation, i found out that GUI usually freezes when a backgroundThread is trying to re-start a finished clip.
When game starts it starts a clip (backgroundAudio), then i create a thread like this:

```
        thread_backgroundAudio = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("THREAD CLIP->"+SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
                do { 
                    if(clip.isActive())
                        do {
                            if(!clip.isRunning() && !(clipWINNING.isActive()) && !(clipLOSING.isActive()) && !(clipLOSING.isRunning()) && !(clipWINNING.isRunning())) {

                                if(playMusic) {
                                    System.out.println("starto la clip nel thread");
                                    clip.start();
                                    clip.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }while(playMusic);
                }while(true);
            }
        };
        thread_backgroundAudio.start();
```

the aim of this thread is to restart the clip if it is finished. I think the problem is in the order of clip.start and clip.setMicrosecondPosition, because if the put .setMicroSecondPosition as first, it doesn't freeze the GUI. But my question is: why should GUI get freezed if this thread is not on EDT?

Comment: Your question is quite broad and vague and hard to answer specifically. Do you do logging? Do you know where the freezing usually occurs?

Comment: Freezing could occur wherever in the program... And i dont know how to log ITT properly...

Comment: I edited the original post @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a SwingWorker should not be necessary in your Code, if you do all time consuming tasks in some daemon threads of you Controller.
For me your problem descriptions sounds like you are doing some major work in the context of the EDT. First thing to check would be in my eyes, the program parts that you run via invokeLater.
If you are starting, maybe a lazy evaluation, as you are already in the EDT, the exact same behavior as you described it in this thread would occur.

Comment: I have thought it too.... but, how can i find that mistake? the problem occurs irregularly and i don't know how to reproduce it. Even if i run my program, and i literally do NOTHING, after X time, GUI is freezed...

Comment: Well if you do nothing, is there a way, the problem could be with one of the methods which are called from the server from time to time?

Comment: @ElMapoMapo A possibility to find out which method blocks you program would be to measure the run time of you program. There you can see where most of the computing time is consumed. Use for example the https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop/blob/master/doc/ConsoleProfiler.md or any other profiler.

Comment: I Will try this option to find out something more interesting...but i was wondering, why shouldn't i implement a swingworker ? I repeat: several threads update GUI with no synchronization at all... only by using swingutilities.invokeLater. I think this would not be a safe practice...

Comment: Does it freeze if you run in a debugger? Some debuggers (like the one in eclipse) have a 'pause' button that can be pressed while the program is running; it will pause at least one thread and give you call stacks you can look at to see what is running at the time. One question this might help answer is whether the program is in some kind of endless loop somewhere or it's just that the UI is nonresponsive for some reason.

Comment: I still don't really know how to use debug... but if you can see my EDIT, there is something new to deal with

Comment: @ElMapoMapo, you ought to be good with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` alone, as long as you diligently use it *everywhere* where a Swing method is invoked from outside of the GUI thread. This includes firing events. As long as this is done everywhere, all access to shared data should be safe, since the GUI thread can only do one thing at a time.